# How to change horizontal recyclerview scrollbar track color and thumb color Programatically in android

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I try this code---but not working

Following are my code in class.

```
 Field mScrollCacheField = View.class.getDeclaredField("mScrollCache");
        mScrollCacheField.setAccessible(true);
        Object mScrollCache = mScrollCacheField.get(recycle);
        Field scrollBarField = mScrollCache.getClass().getDeclaredField("scrollBar");
        scrollBarField.setAccessible(true);
        Object scrollBar = scrollBarField.get(mScrollCache);
        Method method = scrollBar.getClass().getDeclaredMethod("setVerticalThumbDrawable", Drawable.class);
        method.setAccessible(true);
        method.invoke(scrollBar, getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.track));
```

Thanks in advance for help. Any suggestions are welcome.